# linq to join two lists with dynamic sizes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists, `List<Collection> collections` and `List<Invoice>` invoices. Both have a CurrencyID field and a Value field. What I need is to group these two lists by the currencyID and have the collected value substracted of the invoice value. And this only in the case of matching, otherwise, no matter in which list there would be a non match, I will need it in the final list. For example:

```
invoices        collections         final
30 EUR              10 USD          10 EUR
40 CAN              20 EUR          40 USD     
50 USD              50 JPN          40 CAN
                                    50 JPN
```

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: foreach, linq, join, group...and cannot make it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following classes and lists:

```
class Collection { public string CurrencyID; public Int32 Value; }
class Invoice { public string CurrencyID; public Int32 Value; }

...

List<Collection> collections = new List<Collection> {
    new Collection() {CurrencyID="USD", Value=10},
    new Collection() {CurrencyID="EUR", Value=20},
    new Collection() {CurrencyID="JPN", Value=50}
};

List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice> {
    new Invoice() {CurrencyID="USD", Value=50},
    new Invoice() {CurrencyID="EUR", Value=30},
    new Invoice() {CurrencyID="CAN", Value=40}
};
```

You can get what you want doing two simple queries, and then combine them using `Union`.

```
var result1 = (from i in invoices
               let o = collections.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CurrencyID == i.CurrencyID)
               select new 
               {
                  CurrencyID = i.CurrencyID,
                  Value = i.Value - (o != null ? o.Value : 0)
               }).ToList();

var result2 =  from c in collections
               where !result1.Any(x => x.CurrencyID == c.CurrencyID)
               select new 
               {
                CurrencyID = c.CurrencyID,
                Value = c.Value
               };

var result = result1.Union(result2).OrderBy (r => r.Value);
```

**Result**

[image]